# vanlla javascript - why the particle gout is not being drawing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm programing a game in pure js with html5 canvas but I don't understand where is the error and how search for it

CSS https://pastebin.com/RBbw7bvD

HTML https://pastebin.com/0xYUH9Lu

JS https://pastebin.com/s0Pm35TN

I put css because stack gives me error

```
* {

  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}

html, body {

  height:100%;
  width:100%;

}

body {

align-content:space-around;
  background-color:#202830;
  color:#ffffff;
  display:grid;
  <!--justify-content:center;-->

}

canvas {

  background-color:#000000;

}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific with what you're trying to achieve and narrow down code set you're struggling with.

Comment: The line `if (typeof gout == "undefined" && gout == null) {` will never pass, A variable can not be of type `"undefined"` and equal `null` at the same time (`null` is type of `"object"`) Change the line to `if (!gout) {`  same as`"if (gout === undefined || gout === null) {`

Comment: @Blindman67 I didn't know that if can comprobe object in js I have seen it but think was a boolean. thank you so much